# What prevents setting ATI / radeon power_profile from boot and retaining it after suspend?

Tags: 12.04, boot, power-management, suspend, radeon

I'm successfully using the open source radeon driver and use KMS-power_profiles (see link below) for power management of my graphics to prevent overheating. But I can't manage to set the power_profile on boot and retain it after suspend - so I have to do it manually every time I start up or wake up my laptop.

Several questions about setting it at boot were posed at askubuntu and elsewhere and I've tried every way described without success. I'm new to (Ubuntu) Linux but believe I followed the instructions correctly.
Since I cannot comment on the answers as a new users and hours of research on the web didn't help I'm posting this as a new question. Please help :)

I'm using: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250 (family R600) on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with 
Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 = the default open source driver, that came with the installation.

The method most often described is putting

```
echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

in

```
/etc/rc.local
```

before

```
exit 0
```

After doing this I can prove that rc.local *is being executed* (inserted a command to create a directory which worked), but

```
cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

returns `high` instead of `low`.

Again, setting the `power_profile` manually as root (even executing rc.local directly) *does work*. But even then the setting is reverted to `high` after waking up from suspend.

Other ways I've tried without success:

- installing the sysfsutils package and adding a rule to the `/etc/sysfs.conf` file
- putting a script in `/etc/init.d/`

**Is there any reason you could think of that prevents setting radeon power_profile from boot and retaining it after suspend? Could there be another process overriding my settings?**

*Thank you for your help!*

P.S. I don't want to use the proprietary driver for power-management because it brings along other severe problems.

**References:**

- [X.org reference for KMS power management](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature#KMS_Power_Management_Options)
- [How to set power_profile at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115142/how-to-set-power-profile-at-boot)
- [Tweaks and configuration for Radeon Open Source driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149915/tweaks-and-configuration-for-radeon-open-source-driver)
- [Gnome 3 Ati Fan always on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116005/gnome-3-ati-fan-always-on)
- [Ubuntu open source ATI radeon driver power usage tweaks](http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-open-source-ati-radeon-driver-power-usage-tweaks/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still don't know why the other solutions didn't work for me, but finally found a working solution using pm-utils. I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it but it does all I wished for: **Set the radeon `power_profile` to `low` on boot and retain that setting after suspend-resume**.

Step 1: Create hook

```
gksudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile
```

Step 2: Fill in the desired setting

```
#!/bin/sh

echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile

exit 0
```

Step 3: Make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/radeon-power_profile
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

alt-f2:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/init.d/ati-power-save
```

write this in ati-power-save file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ATI power save
echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
```

save and run these commands:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/ati-power-save 
sudo update-rc.d ati-power-save defaults 99
```

[as described in here](http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-open-source-ati-radeon-driver-power-usage-tweaks/)